# wp_mail function works only when wp dashboard is logged in

Tags: wordpress

I am using wp_mail function to send email, but I receive email only when the dashboard is loggedin in a new tab on same browser, if the wp dashboard is closed i dont receive email. can some body help.

please find the code i am using.

```html
add_action( 'wp_ajax_send_message', 'do_send_message' );
function do_send_message() {

  if ( isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) &&isset($_POST['message']) &&isset($_POST['phone']) &&isset($_POST['enquiry'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name']; $email = $_POST['email']; $message = $_POST['message']; $phone = $_POST['phone']; $subject = $_POST['enquiry'];
    $to = "xyz@domain.com";
    
      $body = "\n\nName: $name \n\nphone: $phone \n\nEmail: $email \n\nMessage: $message";

    $success = wp_mail($to,$subject,$body);
            if ($success) return true;       
  }
}
```

Comment: use `add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_send_message', 'do_send_message' );` insteed.

Comment: I tried this no way. Its not working even if dashboard is logged in.

Comment: Oh. actually `add_action('wp_ajax_send_message, 'do_send_message' )` worked for logged in users and `add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_send_message', 'do_send_message' );` worked for non logged in users. so if you want to work for both you have to use both hook

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy..Fixed my problem..u saved my time..cheers..-:)